# Sinon not stubbing property value of object

Tags: sinon, stub

I am using sinon v4.1.2. According to the documentation (http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/sandbox/), I should be able to set a property using the following:

```js
sandbox.stub(myObject, 'hello').value('Sinon');
```

However, I am getting the error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'SinonStub'

What is the real way to do this? I looked through all the available functions, and tried `returnValue`, but that isn't a valid function either.

The following was working on an older version of sinon:

```js
sandbox.stub(myObject, 'hello', 'Sinon');
```

Comment: What is the value of myObject? `{ hello: 'world'}`?

Comment: It's failing in the compile step, it's not running.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works for me with Sinon.JS v4.1.2:

```js
myObject = {hello: 'hello'}
sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
sandbox.stub(myObject, 'hello').value('Sinon')
myObject.hello // "Sinon"
sandbox.restore()
myObject.hello // "hello"
```

Comment: I am not sure what happened before, but now it is working just as it's supposed to. I thought I ran `npm install`, but maybe that didn't work the first time. Thanks for verifying that it works as documented.

Comment: `stub.value` was added in Sinon v2, FWIW.

Answer (score -1):

In my expirience, it's not necessary to create a sandbox everytime. You can use stubs without it to reduce complexity in your code.
Just define a stub like this:

```
const stubHello = sinon.stub(myObject, 'helloFunction');
```

And then you will have all stub powers!

Comment: This isn't really addressing the use case in the question. Westy wants to stub a property, not a function. Plus, it seems the root cause might have been the version he/she was using (as Jonathan indicated). Both the original code in the question and `sinon.stub(myObject, 'hello').value('Sinon')` should work.