# Stub a property using sinon

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sinon

I am trying to use sinon to create a stub instance and use a specific property value in the stub.

This is my code:

```
// MyClass
export default class MyClass {
  public constructor(public readonly myParameter: string) {}
}

// MyClass test
import MyClass from "../src/index";
import sinon from "sinon";

describe("stubs", () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    const myClass = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
    sinon.stub(myClass,'myParameter').value('a');
    expect(myClass.myParameter).toBe("a");
  });
});
```

However this is not working. The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property myParameter
```

Note: I have also checked whether the problem was the promoted constructor property or the fact that it's `readonly` but that does not seem to be it, I have the same problem with a `public myParameter: string` in the class body as well.

What I have tried came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424195/sinon-not-stubbing-property-value-of-object) but it is not working and I don't if this is because this is a stub instance rather than a simple stub, but I don't know how to get it to work.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sinon-sandbox-forked-qd4p2t)

Comment: If you're just trying to set a property, do you need a stub at all? Just `myClass.myParameter = 'a'`, or even use `{ myParameter: 'a' }` as the test double.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. That was helpful. I've added my own understanding of why this is happening and a potential workaround based on this comment

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question to the best of my understanding:

The TS code:

```
export default class MyClass {
  public constructor(public readonly myParameter: string) {}
  public someMethod() {}
}
```

basically translates to a JS class like:

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(myParameter) {
        this.myParameter = myParameter;
    }
    someMethod() { }
}
```

Since I use `createStubInstance` this does result in the constructor not being called and therefore `myParameter` not being set on the instance, so `sinon` is correct to say that it does not exist.

The immediate solutions that work for me are based on @jonrsharpe suggestions. I need to somehow ensure the property exists before I can stub it e.g.:

```js
describe("stubs", () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    const myClass = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
    // "as any" required in TS since property is readonly and transpiler would complain 
    (myClass as any).myParameter = null; 
    sinon.stub(myClass, "myParameter").value("a");
    expect(myClass.myParameter).toBe("a");
  });
});
```

This may seem pointless (and it really is for a string value) but you can just as easily follow this approach for more complex types e.g. if your property is another class for example you could do:

```
const myClass = sinon.createStubInstance(MyMoreComplexClass);
    // "as any" required in TS since property is readonly and transpiler would complain 
    (myClass as any).myClassInstanceParameter = null; 
    sinon.stub(myClass, "myClassInstanceParameter").value(sinon.createStubInstance(MyOtherClass)));
    expect(myClass.myParameter.otherClassMethod).toBe(null); // It's there but no stub behaviour defined
```